# Newb to groovyConsole and struggling with importing Grails converters

Tags: json, grails, groovy, converters, groovy-console

I'll still just a pup when it comes to using Groovy's and Grails' tools. I want to use groovyConsole to test some ideas. The code I want to try involves using Grails converters, json to be exact. I found a nice post that explains how to do this by adding classes to groovy-starter.conf rather than messing around with ClassPath. The last time I tried adding ClassPath all kinds of things went haywire on me!

So I like this idea of adding the code to groovy-starter.conf. I have located that file in $GROOVY_HOME/conf. Here's the article I speak of: [DRY Groovy, How To Get Groovy To Import A Class Into a Script](http://testinfected.blogspot.com/2008/01/dry-groovy-how-to-get-groovy-to-import.html)

The problem: I don't know exactly what to add to this. I want to add `import grails.converters.json` to my groovyConsole script. But being a newb I am not clear on what magic incantation I put in groovy-starter.conf!

I am thoroughly enjoying my newfound love for Groovy, but get a little frustrated when I can't get Google to cough up an answer to my questions. I think I have 75% of the answer but could use a little more guidance. I have JDK 1.6, Groovy 1.6.5 and grails-1.3.5 installed on this system. What magic words will fix my groory-starter.conf so I can access the Grails converters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `grails console` instead of `groovyConsole` - it does load all the application classes, has a database connection and everything.

OTOH, speaking of classes fro `groovyConsole`, you need to load a lot - `$GRAILS_HOME/dist/grails-web-1.3.5.jar`, and all of its dependencies like `grails-core-1.3.5.jar` and mode from `$GRAILS_HOME/lib/`.

Comment: thanks. I hadn't even thought to try grails console. I guess I kind of thought it was the same thing! I will give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this is quite simple : you have to find out in which JARs are the classes json converters. But if I were you, I wouldn't go the hard way.

In Groovy scripts, I tend to prefer the [Groovy Grapes](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape) way. it has the obvious disadvantage of duplicating JARs, as grails converters will be both in grails folder and in Groovy grapes repository one. However, it has the **huge** advantage and allowing you to use a precise version of your dependencies (making you test independant of your Grails installation, that may change over time).

Comment: Ah, I like this answer. I haven't really started using Grapes, but this sounds like this might be a good time to start. I don't use groovyConsole a lot, but I often fire it up while working on some bigger piece of code in IntelliJ to help me test my understanding of some Groovy syntax. ps. I tried to vote this as a good answer, but the site told me I didn't have enough reputation points yet. Apparently 30 years of programming isn't enough!!!

Comment: You could have accepted this as the correct answer to your problem, although I do think @Victor_Sergienko one is far more accurately related to your precise problem.